I am getting a preflight CORs error and am unsure how to handle it
My companies GIS team has created a ArcGIS REST API for us developers to use. It allows us access to the GIS data so we can display the GIS data on our frontend products. I currently have created an endpoint that queries a data layer and returns the query in GeoJSON format. The requests work great on Postman (as expected) however when I make a request from our staging environment in development I get this CORS error.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
My question becomes, is this a frontend CORS error? From what I have read ArcGIS allows ALL cross origin requests which leads me to believe this is a frontend error, but I have no good way to tell and be certain. However I have tried many things. This is the jQuery and AJAX request. Any help would be much appreciated
I tried possibly using a different request type rather than ajax, and I also tried grabbing a token from the application window as well as sending a request to generate one.

Can you give a bit more details about the "endpoint" that you have created?

And, perhaps, a bit more details about how you are setting up the Ajax request?

No, this is first and foremost a server-side issue. Your endpoint responded to the preflight OPTIONS request with a redirect - which it is not allowed to, it needs to respond with 200 OK.

Allow the cors policy at backend api side.

@C3roe Can you elaborate more on this? I know I should be getting a 200, but how do I fully know this is a server side issue?

@KostasMinaidis Here is the Ajax request
        url: NeCentralPons,
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend:
         function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
          console.log(`Bearer ${token}`);
         },
        success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
         console.error(error.status)
        }
       });```

"but how do I fully know this is a server side issue?" - the redirect response came from the server side. Even if something about the request you are making was triggering this, no one will be able to tell from the outside.
